# Why is my PC freezing while I'm copying a file from an external hdd?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, external-hdd, copy

Are more than 200GB of data to transfer, when in 150GB if I open a second window to access the same partition of external hdd, will do system freezes. 
So only mouse moves.

I found this tip:

> The pernicious USB-stick stall problem
>
> Posted Jun 12, 2015 20:41 UTC (Fri) by evultrole (guest, #103116)
>   [Link] I've been fighting with this problem for the last year, and I
>   had no luck with changing any of these. Came across this article many
>   times while seeking an answer, so thought I'd leave what eventually
>   worked for me.
>
> Got the problem fixed with a custom udev rule.
>
> /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/81-udisks_maxsect.rules
>
> SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTR{max_sectors}=="240",
>   ATTR{max_sectors}="32678"
>
> My hangs disappeared after a reboot.

Source: http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/

But I not found the path udev on /usr/lib

This problem occurred on Xubuntu 15.10 and Lubuntu 15.10, 
in LiveCD or Installed on HDD too!

Comment: Does the problem persist if you copy using a different software such as rsync?

Comment: I found Grsync [Grsync is a rsync GUI (Graphical User Interface)]: http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/

Comment: That would do. All you need to do is copy and if there are any errors it will show that.

Answer (score 1):

`udev/rules.d` folder can be in different places on different Linux distros.

So just try searching for `rules.d` or `udev` from your's `/usr` or `/` folder:

```
find /usr -name "rules.d"
```

If nothing found, than have a look system wide:

```
find / -name "rules.d"
```

Than look for folder with `*.rules` files, and create a new file for `max_sectors` rule in it.